# Explain why $Ax = b$ is consistent if and only if $b$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need help understanding some fundamental properties of matrices and functions so any help or explanation is welcome.

Edit: Also can you give me a counter example cause I think that will help me understand it better. Like show me how when $Ax=b$ is inconsistent, then $b$ is not a linear combination.

Comment: Because the image of $A$ is precisely the span of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\ x_k\end{bmatrix}$ and let $A$ have columns $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$.  Notice then that $Ax=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots+x_ka_k$.  Now... if $Ax=b$, what does that say about $b$?  In the other direction, suppose that $b$ *was* a linear combination of columns of $A$., then $b=c_1a_1+c_2a_2+\dots+c_ka_k$ for some constants $c_1,\dots,c_k$.  There should be an obvious choice of $x_1,\dots,x_k$ that achieves the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ for any vector $x$. In particular,  if $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $C_1,\dots, C_n$ are the columns, then $Ax=x_1C_1+\dots+x_nC_n$.

Here's an inconsistent system:   $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end {pmatrix}$, and $b=\begin {pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.  Any linear combination of the columns of $A$ has zero in the second coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

A system of equations is consistent if there is at least one set of values for the unknowns that satisfies every equation in the system.

In the case where you have $Ax = b$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $x$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $b$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^m$, the statement that this system is consistent amounts to saying that there is some $x$ so that the equation holds.

If $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are the columns of $A$, and $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then I leave it to you to apply matrix-vector multiplication to show that if the system is consistent then
$$
x_1A_1+\dots+x_nA_n = b.
$$
Likewise, if $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, i.e., there exist scalars $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that
$$
\alpha_1A_1+\dots+\alpha_nA_n = b,
$$
then define $x = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, and conclude that the system is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a $2\times 2$ matrix $$A=\begin {bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$ and let $$AX=B$$ where you have $$X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}$$

We have $$ax_1+bx_2=b_1$$ and  $$cx_1+dx_2=b_2$$

That is

$$B=x_1 \begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}+x_2\begin{pmatrix}b\\d\end{pmatrix}$$

Similar argument works for $n\times n $ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$Ax$ is a vector which is a combination of columns of $A$. Meaning the subspace spanned by the columns of $A$ is the place where the vectors $Ax$ will lie. The column space could span a 2D plane, 3D space.... $R^n$.

If there is another vector $b$, which does not lie in the subspace spanned by columns of $A$, then it is impossible to try to find $b$ in the subspace spanned by columns of $A$. The only way this happens is when $b$ is not a combination of columns of $A$. Hence to have a solution $Ax=b$ has to be true, which means b has to be a combination of columns of A.